# Getting undefined when using getEnumerator

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, loop

I'm calling a function to enumerate through a list of items with a particular ID\foreign key. When there are no items listed I get the appropriate response back, however, if any records are available I get those records back in the response with "undefined" in front of it. See below.

Ancillary Equipment: 
undefinedSFP RJ-45 (Cisco GLC-T): 1

Any way to remove or filter out "undefined"?

```
// GET ASSOCIATED ANCILLARY EQUIPMENT FOR SITE RECORDS
function getAncillary() {
dfd = $.Deferred();
    var id, strMessage2, str, strFinal;
    parentId = GetUrlKeyValue("ID", false, location.href); 
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    context.load(web);
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Ancillary Equipment");
    var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
    caml.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="LinkID" /><Value Type="Lookup">' + parentId + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    listItems = list.getItems(caml);
    context.load(listItems, "Include(ID, Equipment_x0020_Count, Ancillary_x0020_Equipment)");
    context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        var count = listItems.get_count();
        var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
            id = listItem.get_item("ID");
            varCount = listItem.get_item('Equipment_x0020_Count');
            varEquip = listItem.get_item('Ancillary_x0020_Equipment');
            strMessage2 = varEquip + ": " + varCount + " \n";
            str += strMessage2;
        } 
        if (count > 0) {
            strFinal = "Ancillary Equipment: \n" + str;
        } else {
            strFinal = "No ancillary equipment...";
        }
        dfd.resolve(strFinal);
    }, function() {
        dfd.reject();
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Comment: Try initializing str, strMessage2, strFinal to blank string line `str="" `.

Comment: Perfect, that worked. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote and accept the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see there is some error in your code.

Try initializing the variables you are using like str, strMessage2, strFinal to blank string.

For Example:

```
var str="";
```